# Good library for realtime audio (both sending and receiving)?

Tags: c++, audio, node.js, real-time

I'm thinking about doing realtime audio chatting stuff node.js. However, there currently aren't any good libraries for node for this that I know of. For recording audio, I'd probably open an audio device and read PCM bytes from it - however, I'm not sure about how to go on. I want to have control over the network stuff, e.g. I want to be able to multiplex the traffic through an existing connection, so a library that also handles the network part wouldn't work for me. So, what I think I need:

- a C/C++/JavaScript library that is able to do fast (maybe lossy) realtime audio (de-)compression (maybe optimized for compressing human voices)
- a C/C++/JavaScript library that can ensure that things stay realtime, e.g. takes care of dropping data after jitters - maybe I could also do this part in JavaScript myself

Does this sound sane? What are good libraries for these things?

Comment: what do you mean by "C/C++/JavaScript"?

Comment: @sergio: C or C++ or JavaScript. If it's written in JavaScript, I can use it directly. If it's written in C/C++, I should be able to write bindings for node.js.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a C++ audio library named "Crosstalk".

It's a real-time C++ audio engine that allows you to create and route audio systems in real-time. Basically, the engine takes care of all the audio routing and gives you a simple platform for creating system components (E.g. "Network Input Feed" component connected to a "Low-Pass Filter" connected to a "File Recorder").

It's very easy to use. Here's an example of how to play an mp3 file (These components are provided with the engine):

```
XtSystem system;
XtMp3Decoder mp3Decoder;
XtAudioDevice audioDevice;

long md = system.addComponent(&mp3Decoder);
long ad = system.addComponent(&audioDevice);

system.connOutToIn(md,0,ad,0);
system.connOutToIn(md,1,ad,1);

mp3Decoder.loadFile("../05 Tchaikovski-Swan Lake-Scene.mp3");
mp3Decoder.play();
```

You can check out the API documentation and licensing details here: http://www.adaptaudio.com/Crosstalk

Update: Compatibility with free licenses.

Only the demo version of Crosstalk may be used in conjunction with free licensed software, however, commercial use and distribution of Crosstalk is still not allowed. If you wish to use the Crosstalk demo in free software, just mention in your EULA that your program uses a demo version of Crosstalk, and wherever you provide a link to your software, provide a link to: "http://www.adaptaudio.com/Crosstalk", where they may download it themselves.

**EDIT (01-12-2012):**

Crosstalk has been replaced by an open-source project called "[DSPatch](http://www.flowbasedprogramming.com)". DSPatch is essentially an upgraded version of the routing engine behind Crosstalk that is no longer limited to only audio processing. DSPatch allows you to create and route almost any type of process chain imaginable, and free for personal AND proprietary use :)

Comment: Regarding the licensing conditions: I can't use that library in a software intended to be distributed under a free license, right?